# Javascript file pagination script

Tags: javascript

I want a javascript for file navigation.

For e.g.- I have a folder named 'content' in which there are 'n' no. of html files named like content_000.html, content_001.html to content_nnn.html.

There should be buttons like next and previous, clicking on next button will traverse to next html file whereas previous button will show the previous html file. There should be disable functionality also i.e. if user is currently in the last html file then next button should be disabled similarly if the user is in the first page then previous link should be disabled.

I am instructed not to use ajax or plugins such as jquery. Just simple javascript.

Are there any examples available for the same..? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ask why you can't use JavaScript libraries?

Comment: I think you have posted a similar question earlier.

Comment: not actually.. this question is the requirement of my friend in my team. So I posted on behalf of him, we both need this functionality in our project.

Comment: Hi Randell, do you know any library which can do this stuff.?

Comment: I don't think there is a need for a library in this case.

Comment: Do you write the content_nnn.html files manually? If not — that is, if they are generated dynamically — I would consider putting the pagination logic on the server side.

Comment: Even if they are generated manually, they should be generated programatically given the navigation requirement — even generating static pages with a build script will work fine for this. Depending on JS for navigation is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can have these filenames inside an array and when you click on the buttons extract the array value and use

```
window.location
```

to the array value  ( filename )

When you click on the next button move the array index by 1 and on the back button click decrement the array index by 1. If the array index reaches 0 disable the back button. If it reaches the maximum length disable the next button.

Comment: The index will be reset when the page is left, so this won't work.